# Selector for component not working in conjunction with route provider

Tags: angular

So I followed the tutorial on angular.io (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/). I now have routing set up and my AppComponent has a selector of "app". That works fine. I have the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` tag in my app.html. That also works fine, replacing the content as a I navigate to different routes.

My issue however, is that I have started setting up my own navigation bar and I need to be able to change the bar based on some data I am loading from an API. So I created a separate component called NavigationComponent. I have set the selector to 'navigation-bar' and added the tag `<navigation-bar></navigation-bar>` to my app.html file. But it won't load the component.

What am I doing wrong? Each file is shown below. Thanks!

app.component.ts

```
imports ...

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app/views/app.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/styles/app.css'],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
        AccountService
    ]
})
@RouteConfig([
    ...
])
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Tour of Heroes';
}
```

navigation.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import {AccountService} from "../services/account";

@Component({
    selector: 'navigation-bar',
    templateUrl: 'app/views/navigation.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/styles/navigation.css']
})
export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit {
    isAuthenticated = false;

    constructor(private accountService: AccountService, private router: Router) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.isAuthenticated = this.accountService.checkAuthenticated();
    }

    logout() {
        this.accountService.clearCredentials();
        this.router.navigate(["Login"]);
    }
}
```

app.html

```
<navigation-bar></navigation-bar>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

If there is anything else that would be helpful, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `NavigationComponent` to `directives` list (*inside `AppComponent`'s `Component` decorator*)

```
imports {NavigationComponent} from ..

@Component({
   selector: 'app',
   templateUrl: 'app/views/app.html',
   styleUrls: ['app/styles/app.css'],
   directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,NavigationComponent],
   providers: [
       ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
      AccountService
   ]
})
@RouteConfig([
   ... 
])
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Tour of Heroes';
}
```

Comment: So I did this and it seems to fix part of the issue but the `routerLink` attributes still don't work in the `navigation.html` file.

Comment: @c.dunlap Add `directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]` into `NavigationComponent`'s `Component` decorator definition (as you do for `AppComponent`)